# Handle multiple choise answer in expert system prolog

Tags: prolog, expert-system

I have to add a functionality to an already existing expert system, that is to manage questions with different types of answers, not Boolean, but for example multiple choice answers.
In the knowledge base I currently have askable predicates (Goal, Question) such as `askable(presents(X, Y), ['Present', Y]).`
Askable predicates are predicates that are invoked by the system when we want to get a response from the user.
I want to get for example:

Which colour do you prefer?
Answers to choose from: red, green, yellow.

In the knowledge base i have rules like this:

```
rule (17, manifests (X, 'pica'), and ([
shows (X, general_behavior_6),
shows (X, diagnostic_ criterion_ ingestion_not_food_substances),
shows (X, diagnostic_ criterion_no_medical_condition), 
shows (X, diagnostic_ criteria)
])).
```

How can I handle this? Questions with Boolean answers must remain.

Comment: Is that really Prolog? Also in the example posted you have unbalanced grouping operators, I.e. `(` and `[`.

Comment: sorry if i made a mistake writing the code. And yes, it's prolog, and i didn't right this code my own, but it's the project made by thousand of students of my course.

Comment: I see you fixed it but you still have an unbalanced `(`. Where is the closing `)` that matches this `rule (`?

Comment: Know I fixed, i missed the last ).

Comment: In this `and ([...])`  is `and` a predicate, a functor or something else? I would have expected `and([...])` without a space or `, ([...])` without the `and`, thus the `and` has me confused.

Comment: Also confused about `rule (` and `manifests (` and `shows (`. Is there really suppose to be a space between `rule` and `(`?  Is there really suppose to be a space between `manifests` and `(`?   Is there really suppose to be a space between `shows` and `(`? If there were some [term_expansion/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=term_expansion/2) rules or other [conditional compilation](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=progtransform) it would make sense.

Comment: Also confused about `diagnostic_ criterion_ ingestion_not_food_substances` I would have expected them in a list like `[diagnostic_,criterion_,ingestion_not_food_substances]` or without spaces like `diagnostic_criterion_ingestion_not_food_substances`. Why that notation? What Prolog and version are you using?